# param-set type for LoadBalancerPorts

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use awssum.io to delete load balancer listeners (http://awssum.io/amazon/elb/delete-load-balancer-listeners.html) but I could not figure out what param-set type looks like. I have tried [1000, 2000] but it did not work. Here is partial code:

```
var params = { LoadBalancerName: 'my_balancer_name',
               LoadBalancerPorts: [2000, 3000] };

var config = {};
config.accessKeyId = 'abc';
config.awsAccountId = '123';
config.secretAccessKey = 'def';
config.region = 'us-1';

var elb = new Elb(config);

elb.DeleteLoadBalancerListeners(params, function(err, data)
{
    ....
});
```

Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is lib bug. Here is the fix, the file **node_modules/awssum/lib/elb-config.js**, change from **type: 'param-set'** to **type: 'param-array'**,

```
DeleteLoadBalancerListeners : {
    url : 'http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteLoadBalancerListeners.html',
    defaults : {
        Action : 'DeleteLoadBalancerListeners'
    },
    args : {
        Action : {
            required : true,
            type : 'param',
        },
        LoadBalancerName : {
            required : true,
            type : 'param',
        },
        LoadBalancerPorts : {
            required : true,
            // type : 'param-set',
            type : 'param-array',
            prefix : 'member',
        },
    },
},
```